# How to convert headerless, compressed, pipe-delimited files stored in S3 into parquet using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Currently, I have several thousand headerless, pipe-delimited, GZIP compressed files in S3, totaling ~10TB, with the same schema. What is the best way, in AWS Glue, to (1) add a header file, (2) convert to parquet format partitioned by week using a "date" field in the files, (3) have the files be added to the Glue Data Catalog for accessibility for querying in AWS Athena?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an athena table pointing your data on S3 :

[Create external table on athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html)

2) Create a dynamic frame from glue catalog, using the table you created in above step.

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="{{database}}", table_name="{{table_name}}")
```

3) Write the data back to new S3 location in whatever format you like:

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
   frame = DyF,
   connection_type = "s3",
   connection_options = {"path": "path to new s3 location"},
   format = "parquet")
```

4) Create an athena table pointing your parquet data on S3 :

[Create external table on athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html)

Note : Instead of creating athena table manually, you can also use glue crawler to create one for you. However, that will incur some charges.

Comment: This answers only 1 part of my question

Comment: I have updated the answer for the last part. I cant understand what you mean by "add a header file"? Could you please elaborate. I assumed you want to force a schema on top of the CSV data, which can be done by first step.

Comment: The CSV data files currently have no header (column names) but I have a separate file with that information that I would like to add

Comment: all you need is an athena table. Since you already have the schema and it is unlikely to change, Step 1 above will solve your problem. You don't need to add that extra file containing headers to S3.

Comment: The athena table stores the meta information in glue catalog and the glue etl job will extract the schema from the glue catalogue metadata.